# List of strings to array of integers

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

From a list of strings, like this one:

```
example_list = ['010','101']
```

I need to get an array of integers, where each row is each one of the strings, being each character in one column, like this one:

```
example_array = np.array([[0,1,0],[1,0,1]])
```

I have tried with this code, but it isn't working:

```
example_array = np.empty([2,3],dtype=int)    
i = 0 ; j = 0

for string in example_list:
    for bit in string:
        example_array[i,j] = int(bit)
        j+=1
    i+=1
```

Can anyone help me? I am using Python 3.6.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Are all strings the same length?

Comment: @coldspeed yes, in my case they are all the same length. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a list comprehension because it automatically generates the output list for you, which can be easily converted to a numpy array.  You could do this using multiple for loops, but then you are stuck creating your list, sub lists, and appending to them.  While not difficult, the code looks more elegant with list comprehensions.

Try this:

```
newList = np.array([[int(b) for b in a] for a in example_list])
```

newList now looks like this:

```
>>> newList
 ... [[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```

Note: there is not need to invoke map at this point, though that certainly works.

So what is going on here?  We are iterating through your original list of strings (example_list) item-by-item, then iterating through each character within the current item.  Functionally, this is equivalent to...

```
newList = []

for a in example_list:
    tmpList = []
    for b in a:
        tmpList.append(int(b))
    newList.append(tmpList)

newList = np.array(newList)
```

Personally, I find the multiple for loops to be easier to understand for beginners.  However, once you grasp the list comprehensions you probably won't want to go back.

Answer (score 3):

If all strings are the same length (this is crucial to building a contiguous array), then use `view` to efficiently separate the characters.

```
r = np.array(example_list)
r = r.view('<U1').reshape(*r.shape, -1).astype(int)

print(r)
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1]])
```

You could also go the list comprehension route.

```
r = np.array([[*map(int, list(l))] for l in example_list])

print(r)
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: I have never used map before.  However, I am beginning to appreciate its utility and elegance.  Good application of this built in here.  Thanks for the example.

Comment: A more efficient way would be `r[:,None].view('u4')-48`, though its tricky, Unicode dependent, and hard to understand

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `map`:

```
example_array = map(lambda x: map(lambda y: int(y), list(x)), example_list)
```

The outer `lambda` performs a `list(x)` operation on each item in `example_list`. For example, `'010' => ['0','1','0']`. The inner `lambda` converts the individual characters (resultants from `list(x)`) to integers. For example, `['0','1','0'] => [0,1,0]`.

Comment: In 3.x map returns an iterable (unlike 2.x), so your your solution is incomplete for the OP's need.  How about example_array = [*map(lambda x: [*map(lambda y: int(y), list(x))], example_list).  Though this seems overly convoluted...

Comment: Oh, and don't forget conversion to an array: example_array = np.array(example_array)